# Splunk query to list out by stats from json kind of log

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a splunk log where the log will be in JSON format or as raw data. Need to write a splunk query using stats command.

index=* application_name=abc type=imp | stats count by status

Tried with 'stats count by status' command, but noyhing worked. Also tried as 'stats count by message_text:data' , 'stats count by message_text:data:status'

Log as listed as below,

{"application_name":"abc","type":"imp"},"box":"dev","message_text":"{\"data\":{\"error\":"invalid",\"status\":"200"}}

Need to get the count by status and type

Comment: Use the `spath` command to extract the JSON into fields.  Then use `message_text.data.status` to get the value.

Comment: "index=* application_name=abc type=imp | spath output=myfield path=message_text.data.status "   used that query(within double quotes), unable to get the count of 'status'. Also tried with "index=* application_name=abc type=imp | spath output=myfield path=message_text.data.status | table myfield" but no luck. Any further help please

Comment: One cannot reference any JSON fields before using the `spath` command to extract them.  Try `index=foo | spath | search application_name="abc" type="imp" | stats count by message_text.data.status`

Answer (score 0):

@Sateesh M

Can you please try this?

```
YOUR SEARCH |  rex field=_raw "\"message_text\":\"(?<data>.*)$" | rex mode=sed field=data "s/\\\\\"/\"/g" | eval _raw=data | kv | stats count by "data.status"
```

My Sample Search:

```
| makeresults | eval _raw="{\"application_name\":\"abc\",\"type\":\"imp\"},\"box\":\"dev\",\"message_text\":\"{\\\"data\\\":{\\\"error\\\":\"invalid\",\\\"status\\\":\"200\"}}"
| rex field=_raw "\"message_text\":\"(?<data>.*)$" | rex mode=sed field=data "s/\\\\\"/\"/g" | eval _raw=data | kv | stats count by "data.status"
```

Comment: Tried with this, getting error as 'unbalnced quotes'......YOUR SEARCH |  rex field=_raw "\"message_text\":\"(?<data>.*)$" | rex mode=sed field=data "s/\\\\\"/\"/g" | eval _raw=data | kv | stats count by "data.status"

Comment: Can you please share your search?

is the same as below ?
`index=* application_name=abc type=imp |  rex field=_raw "\"message_text\":\"(?<data>.*)$" | rex mode=sed field=data "s/\\\\\"/\"/g" | eval _raw=data | kv | stats count by "data.status" `

Comment: Yes Kamlesh, it is same as you said, kept the application_name="abc", that is the only difference

Comment: Getting error as Error in 'rex' command:  The regex 'field' does not extract anything . It should specify atleast one named group. Format: (?<name>...).

Comment: **My Sample Search:** is working in your Splunk Instance?? 
Is this the same event pattern like output from `| makeresults | eval _raw="{\"application_name\":\"abc\",\"type\":\"imp\"},\"box\":\"dev\",\"message_text\":\"{\\\"data\\\":{\\\"error\\\":\"invalid\",\\\"status\\\":\"200\"}}"`